# AssemblyInfo.cs , .net applications versions

Tags: c#, .net, versioning, assemblyinfo

I would like to keep version in my .net applications and let the .net to manage it. I don't really understand how it works. Is the version number per project ? How .net manages versions? If anyone could please explain it briefly i will be grateful.

Comment: Please elaborate more what you want to do.

Comment: @Bobby: Understand how versioning works in .NET projects. Don't make it too complicated.

Answer (score 7):

What I usually do is to keep a SolutionInfo.cs that contains all the attributes that are common for the projects of my solution, for example the version-number. I keep this file in the solution root.

I then link that file into the project (right click the project and Add->Exsiting item... -> Add as link (the little arrow on the add button)).

I then can increment the version number in a single place and it will be updated in all the projects that links that file.

For more information on that for example see: http://jebsoft.blogspot.com/2006/04/consistent-version-numbers-across-all.html

Answer (score 3):

The version number is per-project (.csproj file), so per built .dll or .exe file. The version number is embedded in the .dll or .exe, and can be viewed using (for example) Windows Explorer by right-clicking on the file and selecting *Properties*.

MSDN contains an explanatory article about how to use `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/556041

Comment: Probably important to mention that the version that shows up in Windows Explorer is the File Version, not the Assembly Version. The File Version is the one that has no functional effect on a .net application. The Assembly Version is the one that actually affects what DLLs load in an application.

Comment: Thanks for that article link. I have the 4th atom, Revision number, set to '*' and changing nothing but the debug/release setting and rebuilding, I get a sequence of 19247 19336 19367 which makes me wonder what the heck is going into that. The KB says it will increment by one. Must be the New Math or something?!

Answer (score 1):

[AssemblyVersion] is a very big deal in .NET.  Every type in your program is imprinted with the assembly version, it is part of the type identity.  In other words, when the version of your type changes then you should also change the assembly version.  This forces all *other* assemblies that use your type to be recompiled.

One thing you can do is to let the build system automatically increment the version.  You can't call this 'managing the version' by any stretch of imagination.  Because now just rebuilding your assembly, even without making *any* change in the source code, will make your assembly incompatible with other code that uses the types in that assembly.

Clearly this can only work well if you recompile *all* the code in your solution.

Well, that's not great unless you like sword fighting.  Furthermore, sometimes you want to make a simple bug-fix in your code.  The result is an assembly that's still 100% compatible with the original version.  And you don't need nor want to recompile everything else that uses it.  You just want to send that one assembly to your customer.  Clearly that can only work well if you *don't* let the version increment automatically.

So what you really need is some kind of tool that can magically determine that your source code, the publicly visible part of it, is no longer compatible with a previous version.  Or the changes you made to the non-visible part of it are changing the behavior of the code too much to disallow other code that use your types to continue to use it without some changes in their code.

There's only one tool that I know of that can do this, the one we have between our ears.